# Mulesoft Posting XML to SOAP

Tags: xml, soap, mule

I have a JSON body and via DATAMAPPER, I convert the content into XML.  The conversion works successfully, resulting in the XML below if I save the XML into a file location:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns0:Body>
    <ns1:UpdateObject xmlns:ns1="SaaS.website">
      <ns1:sessionKey>sessionKeygoeshere</ns1:sessionKey>
      <ns1:tenantId>tenantIdgoeshere</ns1:tenantId>
      <ns1:commandData>
        <ns1:ObjectId>ObjectIdgoeshere</ns1:ObjectId>
        <ns1:ObjectType>Incident#</ns1:ObjectType>
        <ns1:Fields>
          <ns1:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
            <ns1:Name>FieldName</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Value>1234567</ns1:Value>
          </ns1:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
        </ns1:Fields>
      </ns1:commandData>
    </ns1:UpdateObject>
  </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

However what I need to do is post this XML to a SOAP web service to update records onto a 3rd party website.  My configurations to do this is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd">
    <data-mapper:config name="json_to_pojo_2" transformationGraphPath="json_to_pojo_2.grf" doc:name="json_to_pojo_2"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="json_to_xml" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml.grf" doc:name="json_to_xml"/>

<flow name="temp_arraytoobjectFlow1" doc:name="temp_arraytoobjectFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="temp" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="json_to_xml" doc:name="JSON To XML"/>
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" doc:name="SOAP"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="https://website.com/ServiceAPI/Integration.asmx" mimeType="text/xml" followRedirects="true" contentType="text/xml" keep-alive="true" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="file" doc:name="file">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/Users/eyu/Desktop/xmatters" outputPattern="temparray_result.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </sub-flow>
</mule>
```

Unfortunately when I run the flow and do a post (exact same post as what I use if my outbound point was file), I get the error below:

```
ERROR 2014-04-16 00:27:52,403 [[integration].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://website.com/ServiceAPI/Integration.asmx, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=connector.https.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=20753fe6
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.website.com.ServiceAPI.Integration.asmx', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={followRedirects=true, http.method=POST, keepAlive=true, Content-Type=text/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Entity enclosing requests cannot be redirected without user intervention (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod:225 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://website.com/ServiceAPI/Integration.asmx, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=connector.https.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=20753fe6
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.website.com.ServiceAPI.Integration.asmx', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={followRedirects=true, http.method=POST, keepAlive=true, Content-Type=text/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity enclosing requests cannot be redirected without user intervention
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.setFollowRedirects(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:225)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.getMethod(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.doSend(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:265)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

Already tried the following:

1. Changed the XML schema to be the structure with the soap headers and changed the SOAP payload to "body"
2. Turn off Follow-redirect - more errors
3. Switched operation to jax-ws client but even further errors occurred.
```

Any help would be great appreciated on this.  Details of environment are below:

Mule Studio Version: 3.5.0
Build Id: 201402101410

Running MAC OS X 10.9.2 (13C64) with java versions below:
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: I hope you used the wsdl for the data mapper transformation.Can you post a logger between cxf and the datamapper with #[payload] in it and then edit the post?Please post the wsdl as well.

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for responding.  I tried using both Pojo and transformed it to XML, as well as extracting the soap structure from SOAP UI to for the schema file, but none worked.  Message from payload is 

INFO  2014-04-16 22:50:54,771 [[heat_xmatters_integration].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: the payload goes here [B@eecd282

WSDL: https://css-development.trysaasit.com/ServiceAPI/FRSHEATIntegration.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Btw, I tried the XML on Soap UI and it posted successfully...